# CSS - Flexbox crops left and right part when resizing

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
.d1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 150px;
}
.d1 div {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</div>
  <div>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</div>
  <div>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</div>
</div>
```

I use the above code to display 3 `div`s in a row and this works fine on a full screen. But on a resized window of `width: 150px` for example, it crops the left and right part. I tried to use `overflow: hidden` but the cropping remains. How could I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried setting `flex-wrap: wrap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cropping happens because the words cannot be broken in order to shrink flex elements further. There are such ways to solve the problem: hidden overflow, `word-break: break-all;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;`. Look at the snippet:

```css
body {
    width: 200px;
}
.d {
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.d > div {
    background-color: yellow;
    flex: 0 1;
    flex-grow: 2;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.d1 {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.d2 > div {
    word-break: break-all;
}

.d3 {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h2>It's <code>overflow: hidden;</code>
<div class="d d1">
    <div>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</div>
    <div>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</div>
    <div>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</div>
</div>
<hr>
<h2>It's <code>word-break: break-all</code>
<div class="d d2">
  <div>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</div>
  <div>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</div>
  <div>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</div>
</div>
<hr>
<h2>It's <code>flex-wrap: wrap</code>
<div class="d d3">
  <div>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</div>
  <div>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</div>
  <div>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```